# c++ pointer class

Tags: c++, pointers

if i have class CAnalyzer,
and i want to make a pointer from this class to new class name CManager.
how can i do it?
note: i need to make the pointer inside init func in CAnalyzer.
thanks

Comment: If you have a class CAnalyzer, you are using the icky Microsoft naming convention where every class starts with a 'C'.  If you decide to change it from a class to a structure, you will have to change CAnalyzer to SAnalyzer **in every file that references CAnalyzer**.  Better not to encode data types in names.

Comment: @Thomas: "class" is not a data type.

Comment: @Itjax: please state your reference.  "With object-oriented programming, a programmer can create new data types to meet application needs. Such an exercise as known as "data abstraction" and the result is a new class of data.", http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/data-type

Comment: @Thomas: I'm talking about the keyword "class" (hence no article) which is not a data-type, but an identifier that a data-type definition or declaration will follow. A class (now with an article, hence something that you defined using "class") however is a data-type (which is what you're quoting) - but the class surely doesn't have a data-type (it has a meta-type, which is "class").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By init func, did you mean the constructor?

```
CAnalyzer::CAnalyzer()
{
    CManager *pManager = new CManager();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class CManager;  // Forward declaration (may not be needed)

class CAnalyzer
{
    // Other stuff goes here

private:
    CManager   *p_manager;
};
```

I don't understand what you mean by "*I need to make the pointer inside init func in CAnalyzer*".

Comment: +1 I wasnt sure either, but your guess might be more right than mine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, so I will guess.

You want to write a member function of `CAnalyzer` that returns a pointer to a new instance of a `CManager`?  You can do that like this:

```
CManager* CAnalyzer::CreateManager()
{
  return new CManager;
}
```

You should, however, use smart pointers rather than raw pointers in the interest of robust programming.

Comment: Shouldn't that be CreateManager?

Comment: @DeadMG:  Yeah, probably.  Fixed